# Maelstrom Profile

Tags: geometry-nodes

**A node-noob calling all node-geniuses!**

This is what I'm after:

[image]

However, at present, points are only being generated on the *curve* profile of the object specified below. These points are then being converted to a volume and then a mesh. What I need is for points to be generated *inside* that curve profile too, such that I end up with a solid volume.

[image]

This is a partial snippet of my node layout, and is - I suspect, where the problem lies. The full layout is available in the linked [[project file]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EaNjK2LU1FA_AUmlEFB_8JSfUz8vvHPO/view?usp=sharing) here.

[image]

---

**Update 1**

[image]

I've tried modifying the nodes, replacing [distribute points on faces] with [distribute points in volume] but the model vanishes.

Comment: ...and as helper for no money helping in our free time without getting anything for it - you should provide a blend file to make as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: You're right, I've provided a link in the desc now (y)

Comment: The *distribute points in volume* node should do exactly that

Comment: Sounds like it should do the trick. Tried it out and I've gotten something in error. Could you take a look at the update and help me out on why my model's disappeared?

Comment: **fist of all**, what are you trying to generate as the outcome, because if you share that piece of information we can give you a better answer. **Second of all**, can you share what the error on the _distribute points in volume_ days, that could be the solution. **Last of all**, try filling caps on the curves to mesh.

Comment: Hi Shmuel, I've added an update. Please let me know if this helps and if a 'desired outcome diagram' is something you wish were 'standard submission' in these forums. 

Re. second point, there isn't an error as such: the model just disappears, as shown in photo-4.

Re. point 3, perhaps there is a way I could do so procedurally, but I would appreciate an example blend file on how exactly to do that. If it isn't procedural, then I resist using this as an option.

Comment: In the node `Curve to Mesh` enable *Fill Caps*, then use `Mesh to Volume` and after that you can use `Distribute Points in Volume`.

Comment: @Quellenform you absolute beauty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER RE @QUELLENFORM 19.04.2023:

"In the node `Curve to Mesh` enable `Fill Caps`, then use `Mesh to Volume` and after that you can use `Distribute Points in Volume`."

[image]
^ Working node configuration.